# htmlentities para elementos de array

Tags: php, html

Buen día! 
Estoy armando una app que tiene una secciòn noticias que las toma desde una base de datos. 
Dado que en la base de datos (que ya estaba hecha) los textos tienen varios carácteres especiales que quiero limpiar, para lo cual utilicé 
htmlentities($string)
Sin embargo, cuando hago eso el texto desaparece.

Sin utilizar htmlentities, se ve así

> De acuerdo al Decreto 49/2014 publicado en el Bolet�n Oficial, se ampli� el listado de patolog�as que pueden ser producidas por la

Cuando lo utilizo, esto se elimina.

Les muestro el código porque quizas algo esté haciendo mal
Gracias!

```
      <?PHP

       /*  include('lib/helper/ArticleTextExtractor.php'); */

       $i = 1;

       $SQL_NEWS=" SELECT titulo, copete, cuerpo, imagen, id FROM novedad 
    ORDER BY orden asc LIMIT 3";

    $QUERY_NEWS=mysql_query($SQL_NEWS);

    WHILE($NEWS = mysql_fetch_row($QUERY_NEWS)){
        // Remove HTML code from the "Cuerpo" field and leave only 
    paragraphs with article's plain text.
        $NEWS_FLAT = extractArticleText($NEWS[2]); */

      ?>
      <div class="col-sm-3 notaHome">
       <img src="/web/uploads/novedad/<?php echo $NEWS[3] ?>" class="img-
       thumbnail" alt="">
      <h4 class="azul tituloNota"><?php echo htmlentities($NEWS[0]) ?></h4>
      <hr class="azul">
      <h5 class="subtituloPrincipal subtituloNota"><?php echo 
     htmlentities($NEWS[1]) ?>.</h5>
      <?php echo ($NEWS[2]) ?>
      <a href="novedadesDetalle.html" id="leerMas" role="button" class="btn 
    btn-primary">SEGUIR LEYENDO <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-
    right"></span></a>
    </div>
      <?php

      $i++;

      }

    ?>
```

El codigo que esta comentado, no lo hice yo. De todas formas llama a una funcion extractArticleText que es la siguiente:

```
    <?php
      function extractArticleText($htmlString) 
      {
       $replaced = preg_replace("/<a(.|\\n)*?>(.|\\n)*?<\/a>/", "", $htmlString); // remove anchors
       $replaced = preg_replace("/<(.|\\n)*?>|(&nbsp;)/", "", $replaced); 
      //remove HTML tags and &nbsp;
     return $replaced;
    }
    ?>
```

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes establecer el juego de caracteres en la conexion a la base de datos por ejemplo(PDO):

```
$base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=asocacion_db', 'root', '');

$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8"); //Estableciendo juego de caracteres
```

con Mysqli;

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Otra manera es colocando antes de cualquier salida o etiqueta `html` en el encabezado de tu documento `php` un header como este;

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Tambien puedes agregar en la etiqueta `meta` el uso de caracteres

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto!
(en realidad lamentablemente se usa aún mysql y no mysqli ni pdo, con lo cual la solución fue:
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conexion);

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificarle la codificacion `utf-8` en el tercer parametro del metodo [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) para que muestre los acentos correctamente. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($NEWS[0], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ?>
```